javascript api and storage pagination
I have been looking for documentation on how to retrieve storage whith pagination.
for example api.query.staking.erasStakersPaged
Takes an era, validator, and optional page number (I guess).
As far as I understand it must be possible to omit the page number or to provide a page number.
How are those queries run with the Javascript API?
